# Изменить метку [spark] на [apache-spark]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки

Сейчас с меткой [spark](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark) два вопроса, причём один из них относится к Apache Spark, а другой к веб-фреймворку Spark. Возможно стоит разделить как-то эти вопросы и для Apache Spark сделать соответствующую метку [apache-spark](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-spark) (аналогичная метка как раз имеется в enSO)?

Comment: ...или (ещё и) добавить метку [tag:spark-framework]?

Comment: да, надо отделить apache-spark

Comment: и нужно [apache-spark] и [spark] сделать синонимами или перенести описание метки.

Comment: @AlexChermenin "сделать синонимами" противоречит "разделить". Проще руками перенести описание.

Comment: @NickVolynkin разделил `apache-spark` и `spark-framework`. думаю, что просто `spark` лучше сделать синонимом первой.